# Regex Links to On Page Anchors

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to use a regular expression to convert links to on page anchors. I am totally new to regex, I have tried learning.

I have used a php string replace to the root url with # but need to use preg_replace to change the / to - but not when / is part of a html tag such as `</` or `/>`.

```
$string = '<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/something/somethingelse">Hello World</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/something/somethingelse">Hello World</a></li>
</ul>';

// Replace root url with #
$string = str_replace('http://www.somedomain.com/', '#' , $string);

// This replaces the / with hyphens, but I need it to not do this if is preceeded or followed by < or >
$string = preg_replace("/\//", "-", $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of:

```
preg_replace('/([^<]|^)\/([^>]|$)/', '$1-$2', $string);
```

But the entire task does not look like a reliable way of solving the original task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although am not sure what it does? I want to replace / from a string but not if it is </ or />

Comment: Sorry, there was a set of mistakes. I don't know why did I write that - maybe I was too tired. Now it is fixed and tested.

Comment: Also, the regex can be simplified, if you don't need the slashes at the edges of the entire string: `/([^<])\/([^>])/s`